# Parser Combinator Failing Fast in AST with Position Choices

Tags: parsing, parsec, parser-combinators

I wrote some parser combinators to build an AST with source location information. Profiling indicates that at least 30% percent of execution is spent repeatedly parsing unnecessary information to generate source location data. I need help finding an alternative approach to improve performance.

## Problem

Let's say that I am parsing a language consisting of only two tokens: 'A' and 'B'. To generate AST nodes, I currently defined a combinator that extracts location and builds the node:

```
// Parse body and build resulting node from function
// nodeFactory called with position and result from body.
var node = function(body, nodeFactory) {
    return bind(
        locParser, // get the current location in the token stream
        body,
        prevEnd, // get the previous end position in the token stream
        function(o, x, c) {
            return always(f(Location(o, c), x));
        });
};

var a = node(char('A'), buildNodeA);
var b = node(char('B'), buildNodeB);
```

The issue with this approach is that `locParser` is always run regardless of if body will succeed:

```
var element = either(a, b);
var program = many(element);
run(program, "AAABBA");
```

#### Expected behavior

`a` fails as soon as it is clear that its `body` will fail.

#### Actual Behavior

For 'B' tokens, first `locParser` for `a` is run and when `body` fails, `locParser` for `b` is run. With nesting and more branching, this becomes a performance problem.

#### Edge cases

The location encompasses the entire range of consumed input:

```
var c = node(next(char(' '), char('C')), buildNodeC);
```

A 'C' node's location starts at the start of the space character.

```
var d = node(between(char('('), char(')'), char('D')), buildNodeD);
```

A 'D' node's location starts at the start of '(' and ends at the end of ')'. Both of these cases are correctly handled by `node`.

## Question

How can I refactor these parsers to fail quickly but still access the correct location data?

I would prefer to keep each parser fairly self contained and avoid repeating logic. Additionally, the nodes must not be modified after construction.

Comment: Have you looked at the [papers](http://citeseer.uark.edu:8080/citeseerx/search?q=parser+combinator&submit=Search&sort=rlv&t=doc) on parser combinators. They might hold your answer.

Comment: You'll likely get more attention for your question if you tag it with a language. There are in general many more followers of language tags than problem domain tags.